# How can I use Android exported SQLite database in Java application

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have android app with a SQLite database. I need all the data in my Java application. I have exported database file. Does it work with Java application if my Java application is using SQLite database?

Comment: Is there any difference in the structure of database files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`I have an android app with SQLite database. I need all the data in my Java application. I have exported the database file. Does it work with my Java application if my Java application is using the SQLite database ?`

`Is there any difference in the structure of database files?`

The answer is: **YES, it will work**. There is no change in the database structure.

What you asked is similar to: `Does the structure of a CSV file change if I access it from VB NET, from C# or from Java?`.
The answer to this question is obviously **NO, it won't change**.
It would be a real nightmare if different apps would change the formats of the files they use.